# Sqflite data is lost after app update/upgrade

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-manifest, sqflite

I'm building an app that uses [sqflite^2.0.2](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite) to store data as a local database.

Everything works fine, but the problem arises when updating the application on the device: **all the data is lost**. It seems like the database gets deleted once the app it's upgraded or reinstalled. The behaviour it's the same on an Android emulator.

I've already tried adding `android:allowBackup="true"` in the **AndroidManifest.xml**, and it's still not working even if - as [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup#Files) states - should backup the databases.

Since the database structure it's not being updated, but only the actual Flutter application is, the Database version should remain **1** (?).

```
static Future<Database> init() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  final database = openDatabase(
    join(await getDatabasesPath(), 'myDatabase.db'),
    onCreate: (db, version) {
      return db.execute(
        'CREATE TABLE myOrders (id TEXT PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, quant INTEGER)',
      );
    },
    version: 1, 
  );
  return database;
}
```

The code above initializes my DB, and the `join()` returns the follwing path: `/data/user/0/com.example.myapp/databases/myDatabase.db`

Unfortunately, this didn't help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62845264/11442598

Am I missing something? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Problem solved.

At first, I tried using [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) to be sure the right path was being used everytime for the database. That didn't work, but it was still a good practice for iOS [as recommended](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEWI2.png) by [sqflite](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite).

The next step was to rename the database to something else, maybe there was more that one instance of a DB (?).

Then I've deleted and downloaded again my Android Emulator, choosing one that had [Google Play installed](https://proandroiddev.com/install-google-play-store-in-an-android-emulator-82cd183fefed).

At last, I added the

```
<application android:allowBackup="true"/>
```

string into the `AndroidManifest.xml`

---

I ran a `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get` between all these actions.

After a few tries, the data was not lost anymore.